# how to clear individual columns in oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

i wrote a java app that communicates and stores data in oracle; my question is how do i clear entered information from individual columns in oracle? for example, say i have a following table:

`create table example (id integer, name varchar(50), surname varchar(50));`

and it contains current information, how do i then clear individual columns, but keep the rest intact? For example, what if I wanted to clear name and surname columns, but leave id column intact, how would i go about doing that?
I tried by creating a new table and just copying the id column and then creating name and surname again from scratch like so:

`create table example1 as select id from example`

and then issuing the `alter table` command to add name and surname. Seems a bit redundant but there must be an easier way,

thanks

Comment: Is that really what you want to do?  Is this table just used temporarily, while the page is running?  Otherwise, I agree with other answers that this is a strange thing to do.  Homework perhaps?

Comment: yes it is homework. I have created a java program that simulates a motoGP race. The table stores rider_id, rider_name, rider_lap_time etc.... Prior to start_race command I store their ids and names. Once the start_race command is issued I then add an additional column additional rider_lap_time column. One of the requirements of my specification is that if the start_race command is issued twice in succession, the race must be restarted, but all the rider data must be kept intact. This is why I wanted to know how to clear columns - so I could clear the rider_lap_time columns for each new race.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET name='', surname='' WHERE ...
```

or

```
UPDATE table SET name=null, surname=null WHERE ...
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure your table's constraints allow these values.

This sounds like an odd thing to do though, rarely in an application do you need to do something like "Take ever single user/customer/account we have and erase their firstname from the datastore".

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are nullable you could just run a query to null them:

```
UPDATE example set name=NULL, surname=NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE example
   SET name = NULL
     , surname = NULL;
```